# On showing that if an algebra is closed under countable disjoint unions then it is a sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

The exercise is to show that an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ in $X$ is a $\sigma-$algebra if and only if, for any sequence $(A_n)$ of mutually disjoing elements of $\mathcal{A}$, we have $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \in \mathcal{A}$.

One direction is trivial. For opposite direction, let $(A_n)$ be an arbitrary sequence of sets in $X$. We construct a new sequence $(B_n)$ where $B_1 = A_1$ and $B_n = A_n \setminus (B_1 \cup \dots \cup B_{n-1})$. The proof that $B_n$ is mutually disjoint is in place: Without loss of generality, let $i > j$ where both $i$ and $j$ are positive integers. We have \begin{align*}
B_i \cap B_j & = (A_i \setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^{i-1}B_k) \cap B_j,\\
& = (A_i \setminus (B_j \cup \underbrace{\bigcup_{\substack{k=1,k\neq j}}^{i-1}B_i}_{R})\cap B_j,\\
& = A_i \cap (B_j \cup R)^C \cap B_j,\\
& = A_i \cap B_j^C \cap R^c \cap B_j,\\
& = \emptyset.
\end{align*}

Now I am having trouble showing that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_n$. Notice that $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(A_n \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}B_i\right) = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}(A_n \setminus B_i).$$Maybe I am missing some variant of the De Morgan's laws.

**Edit:** Some explicit computations, we have \begin{align*}\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n & = B_1 \cup B_2 \cup B_3 \cup \dots,\\
& = (A_1 \setminus \emptyset) \cup (A_2 \setminus B_1) \cup (A_3 \setminus \underbrace{(B_1 \cup B_2)}_{A_1 \cup A_2}) \cup (A_4 \setminus (B_1\cup B_2 \cup B_3))\cup \dots
\end{align*}

**Solution?**

The idea is to use induction. The base case $n = 1$ is direct. So let $n-1$ be a positive integer such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}B_i = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}A_i$. Then we have, \begin{align*}
\bigcup_{i=1}^nB_i & = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}B_i\cup B_n,\\
& = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}B_i \cup (A_n \setminus \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}B_i\right)),\\
& = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}B_i \cup \left(A_n \cap \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}B_i\right)^C\right),\\
& = \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}B_i\cup A_n\right) \cap \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}B_i \cup \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}B_i\right)^C\right),\\
& = \bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i \cap X = \bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i.
\end{align*}

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What can help is to argue the equality by showing that any element of $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$ is in $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ and vice versa.

Comment: Will $A\setminus B = A\cap B^c$ help at all?

Comment: @Rik93 Didn't thought about that, thanks for the idea!

Comment: @DilipSarwate Well I was using it in the middle of the first part of the exercise but didn't thought about using it with a little detail in the second proof. I think it is done. Thanks!